# Erlang (rebar?): fixing "potentially included by two different application" errors

Tags: erlang, rebar

So I need to build [riak](http://basho.com/riak/%E2%80%8E) from git snapshot, (note: there's also a recent official snapshot sharing same problem).

During build, following happens:

```
Generating dev1 - node='dev1@127.0.0.1' yzsolrjmx=10013 yzsolr=10014 pbc=10017 http=10018 handoff=10019
(cd rel && ../rebar generate target_dir=../dev/dev1 overlay_vars=vars/dev1_vars.config)
==> rel (generate)
ERROR: generate failed while processing /tmp/riak/rel: {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,"Module mochijson2 potentially included by two different applications: mochiweb and rabbit."}},
```

It looks like a classic "from where to inherit" problem, and I don't think that excluding either module completely from distribution will help (although, if it does - I'm going to expunge rabbit support if it stays for RMQ).

---

However, it's even more strange: `grep` for rabbit shows no source tree points, where it can nbe removed. WTF?

Comment: Resolved by using binary build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem when reltool finds two applications share the same module.

Do you have rabbit somewhere around /tmp/rabbit or maybe it's installed in ERL_LIBS?

Answer (score 0):

just add follow line to reltool.config file.

`{app, mochiweb, [{incl_cond, exclude}]},`