# rebar generate "Module application_starter potentially included by two different applications: kernel and xxx."}},

Tags: erlang, rebar

I have a application which use "included_applications"

It works fine, but if I use rebar(2.6) to generate release, It shows error message

```
"Module application_starter potentially included by two different applications: kernel and xxx.",
```

Can anyone tell me how to do, Thank you

below is main application

```
{application, top,
 [{description, ""},
  {vsn, "1"},
  {modules, []},
  {registered, []},
  {included_applications, [bsc]},
  {start_phases, [{init,[]}, {go,[]}]},
  {applications, [kernel, stdlib, sasl]},
  {mod, {application_starter,[top_app,[]]}}
 ]}.
```

below is included application

```
{application, bsc,
 [{description, ""},
  {vsn, "1"},
  {modules, []},
  {registered, []},
  {start_phases, [{go,[]}]},
  {applications, [kernel, stdlib, sasl]},
  {mod, {bsc_app,[]}}
 ]}.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erlang (rebar?): fixing "potentially included by two different application" errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632470/erlang-rebar-fixing-potentially-included-by-two-different-application-erro)

Comment: I have read this post, and I have search the keyword "application_starter" in my project(include deps), it only appear at *.app.src file.
I think the "application_starter" module is blong to kernel, I just put the module name at *.app.src file

Comment: That question seems not to be a duplicate, since `application_starter` is not supposed to be present in the application to begin with.